# Excel formula fill invalid cells with zero value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel file that contain similar to following:

[image]

**I use** `=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,F$1,$B:$B,$E2)` **formula to convert above content to following:**

[image]

but my formula fill invalid cells with zero value.
I want to leave invalid cells empty. **what changes I must apply to my formula?**

Answer (score 0):

I found answer by own.
this problem can solve by following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,F$1,$B:$B,$E2)>0, SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,F$1,$B:$B,$E2), "")
```

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya after 2 days i can accept it

Comment: It depends upon you. Whether you want to accept or not, just informed, so a solved answer may help someone in the future looking for a solution.